# S3 File upload using Play-S3 fails for images but works for text files

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, playframework, playframework-2.4

I am trying to upload a file to S3 using Scala Playframe work `2.4.1`  Specifically using the module play-s3 `7.0.2`

I can get it to work for text files but when I try and upload an image I get this message, `The provided 'x-amz-content-sha256' header does not match what was computed.`

If I swap "avatar.jpeg" for "text.txt" and "image/jpeg" for "plain/text" in the following code it works.  The text file gets uploaded to S3. But if I try and upload an image (I've tried jpeg and png) it fails saying the header doesn't match.  I have no idea what I am doing wrong at this point and it is driving me nuts.

```
import fly.play.s3.{BucketFile, S3, S3Exception}
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}

def test() = Action
{ implicit request =>

    val file_path = "/path/to/file/avatar.jpeg"
    val bucket = S3("path_to_bucket")
    val byte_array = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file_path))

    val result = bucket + BucketFile("avatar.jpeg", "image/jpeg", byte_array)
    result.map { unit =>
        Logger.info("Saved the file")
    }
        .recover {
            case S3Exception(status, code, message, originalXml) =>
            {
                Logger.info("Error: " + message)
                Logger.info("originalXml: " + originalXml)
            }
        }

    Ok("Yay")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is to not use play 2.4.1.  There is something wrong with the hashing of binary data with 2.4.1. 2.4.2 works just fine though.

https://github.com/Kaliber/play-s3/issues/70